# Not able to run my eclipse maven project- eclipse not recognising mySql-connector-java

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I am nor able to run my eclipse maven project. I keep getting the following error in the problems tab

```
Archive for required library: 'C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.38/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar' in project 'Inspirations' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file
```

In my pom.xml file I have defined the dependency as

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try delete mysql folder in your repository and go to eclipse -> Maven --> Update Project.
If not working, i thinh u can try another version.